# Undefined symbols when attempting to use CoverStory with iPhone app: _vproc_transaction_end, _vproc_transaction_begin

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-coverage, gcov, coverstory

After following [these steps to set up an iphone project with CoverStory](http://www.cubiclemuses.com/cm/articles/2009/05/14/coverstory-on-the-iphone/), my build fails with two linker errors.

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_vproc_transaction_end", referenced from:
      _gcov_exit in libgcov.a(_gcov.o)
      _vproc_transaction_end$non_lazy_ptr in libgcov.a(_gcov.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vproc_transaction_end$non_lazy_ptr)
  "_vproc_transaction_begin", referenced from:
      ___gcov_init in libgcov.a(_gcov.o)
      _vproc_transaction_begin$non_lazy_ptr in libgcov.a(_gcov.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vproc_transaction_begin$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using Xcode  3.2, GCC 4.2 on Snow Leopard. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get gcov running with Xcode 3.2.2, GCC 4.2 on Snow Leopard:

http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/SnowLeopardGCov

Answer (score 1):

Did you add "-lgcov" to Other Linker Flags as the Web page directs?

What is the value of the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET setting? [This page](http://osdir.com/ml/xcode-users/2009-09/msg00057.html) and [this page](http://atastypixel.com/blog/2009/11/29/unit-testing-and-coverage-with-xcode/) suggests the value needs to be set to 10.6.

Comment: Yep, OTHER_LDFLAGS=-lgcov. MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=Mac OS X 10.5. 10.6 doesn't seem to work for the simulator, tried switching to 10.6 and got: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o. Ran 'locate crt1.10.6.o' and didn't see one under /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/. Looks like the Sim is compiled for 10.5 only?

Comment: Curious if anybody has been able to get gcov running with Xcode 3.2, GCC 4.2 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Not me, I get the same exact error. Also using SenTest, if that means anything.